# Way to store string methods in a variable and attach to another variable containing string so they run?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, methods, replace

I have a large string, which is console output converted to html stored in a variable and wanted to replace some of the lines for specific properties in the output.  Was thinking I could just use the `replace` method, but would need to use it like 10 times or so and I am pulling what needs to be replaced from properties in an array so it won't be the same every time. Is there a way I could create a string of all the replace methods and attach to the other variable?  This is what I mean

I put in a variable, `$RMeth` that looks like

```
<table>
<tr><td>Number:</td><td>44343222</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tasks:</td><td>TASK24</td></tr>
<tr><td>ActionType:</td><td>Add</td></tr>
<tr><td>Requested:</td><td>Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>User:</td><td>User1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Department:</td><td>Interenet</td></tr>
<tr><td>HostName:</td><td>GHFIYYG34343</td></tr>
<tr><td>FQDN:</td><td>Domain.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Serial:</td><td>4503344444</td></tr>
<tr><td>IPAddress:</td><td>111.111.111</td></tr>
<tr><td>ADDomain:</td><td>domain.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Reason:</td><td>Testing</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

There is formatting information about that but the table is all I'm trying to modify. `<td>ADDomain:<` this is the property of my output, `<td>domain.com` This is the value.  I want to replace `<td>ADDomain:` with `<td class="ADDomain">ADDomain:</td>` so it will apply the formatting I created in the header to each of the properties.  This is the only way I know how I can modify each property individually in the results.  I wanted to reuse this and won't always have specifically these properties for the report so was getting all the properties from unconverted output by piping the results to gm and selecting the noteproperty then I tried multiple methods of looping through the properties and replacing each line with matching property name.

```
$RMeth = Foreach($property In $Properties){
    ".Replace(""<td>$($Property):"",""<td class=""$Property"">$($property):</td>"")"
}
```

Then I tried adding it to the results to replace but didn't work.

```
($HTMLResults)."$RMeth"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you create this string from _properties in an array_ ? There may be a much better way to construct something other that a string that needs to be interpreted like this.

Comment: The downside of this replacement scheme is that `apple` gets replaced with `Applele`

Comment: So you want to change  <td>xxx</td> to <td class="xxx">xxx</td> for every lines (Number, Tasks, ActionType, ...)?

Comment: Yes that is what im trying to do.  but instead of specifying xxx for each line, i am trying to use the properties i have stored in a varialbe which is Number, Tasks, ActionType,... so if i end up with more properties, or want to use it for other output i dont have to change everytime

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and best practice way is not to put it in a variable but in a function:

```
Function RMeth($string, $props){
    $props.Keys | % {
        $string = $string.replace($_, $props.Item($_))
    }
    $string
}

$properties = @{
    ban="banana"
    app="apple"
}

$yourDataString = "yourstring with app and ban and ..."

RMeth -string $yourDataString -props $properties
```

Comment: Okay but how would i add it in the function?  I wont know what all i need to replace everytime i will have properties coming from somewhere else that will be different sometimes so i am taking those and creating the string with them, im not typing them out like shown in your function

Comment: Can you post an example of your array with properties?

Comment: $props = 
app,
ban,
pine,
rasp,
apri

like so, but that is a simple example.  I will be pulling property names from result list adding other text to replace it with. that wont be the same everytime so i wont be able to just list them out each time. like the below

$Replace = Foreach($property In $Properties){
    ".Replace(""$Property "",""$property"" : some other text)"
}

Comment: that doesnt seem to replace anything.  Is the .keys required?  If i pipe $props to get member in the function to see the results, its just a string, there is no keys property.  If i put the $props variable below the $string variable it lists all my properties i supplied to the paramater

Comment: I tested the code again and for me it outputs a replaced string. $properties is passed to $props and $properties is a hastable not a string and so is $props. Above $string and below $string, also tested. Did you copy paste my whole code and then run it? Which powershell version do you have? ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216269/discussion-between-gerrit-geeraerts-and-keets).

Comment: powershell version 5.1  I probably messed it up

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are after, but you can use a script block to execute something similar:

```
$str = 'Replace my app with a ban.'
$rmeth  = {param($s) $s.Replace("app","Apple").Replace("ban","Banana").Replace("pine","Pineapple").Replace("rasp","Raspberry").Replace("apri","Apricot")}
& $rmeth $str
```

---

Regex replacement (`-replace` for case-insensitive or `-creplace` for case-sensitive) is going to be better than string replacement if your strings already contain your desired words. For example, `'apple'.Replace('app','Apple')` yields `Applele`. The `.Replace()` method is also case-sensitive. With regex you can add more options to your match conditions.

Below is an example using regex matching with a word boundary `\b`. This ensures that `I like to eat an app.` performs a replacement but `I want an apple.` performs no replacement.

```
# $replacements is a hash table of your lookup strings and their replacements
$str = 'Replace my app with a ban.'
$replacements = @{'app'='apple';'ban'='banana';'pine'='pineapple';'rasp'='raspberry'}
$replacements.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
    $str = $str -replace "\b$($_.Key)\b","$($_.Value)"
}
$str
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid that because i suck at regex.  Also the fruit was just an example wasnt able to get what i was using for at the time. but it will be an array of properties from psobject that is created in the script.  I want to convert those objects to html and am then trying to replace the lines that contain the property names so i can apply formatting to them.  In this script i know the properties but if i ever want to reuse it for other output ill have to change the properties each time so was trying to find a way to take the properties and then replace each one in the results reuse.

Comment: @Keets I added another example that comes close to what you are asking. It is definitely not clear to me what you really want. I don't think using hypothetical, simplistic examples is helping anyone get closer to your ideal solution.

Comment: didnt have full script, used examples, added more details now.  The line i tested with the function may have not worked because html format was treated like a regex syntx?